# failed to load external entity error on SOAP

Tags: php, soap

i am call a web service which is locate on https protocol.
and i get "failed to load external entity" error while calling it.

as i search on google it is because in PHP5, SOAP class will not parse WSDL file located on a secure HTTPS connection.

what is the solution? i don't want to use http instead of https.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To be able to read from secure protocol (https), you need to have **openssl** extension turned on from php.ini in the extensions section.